# read_csv file in pandas reads whole csv file in one column

Tags: csv, pandas

I want to read csvfile in pandas. I have used function:

```
ace = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\C313586\\Desktop\\Daniil\\Daniil\\ACE.csv',sep = '\t')
```

And as output I got this:

a)First row(should be header)

```
_AdjustedNetWorthToTotalCapitalEmployed _Ebit _StTradeRec _StTradePay _OrdinaryCf _CfWorkingC _InvestingAc _OwnerAc _FinancingAc _ProdValueGrowth _NetFinancialDebtTotalAdjustedCapitalEmployed_BanksAndOtherInterestBearingLiabilitiesTotalEquityAndLiabilities _NFDEbitda _DepreciationAndAmortizationProductionValue _NumberOfDays _NumberOfDays360

#other rows separated by tab
0   5390\t0000000000000125\t0\t2013-12-31\t2013\tF...
1   5390\t0000000000000306\t0\t2015-12-31\t2015\tF...
2   5390\t00000000000003VG\t0\t2015-12-31\t2015\tF...
3   5390\t0000000000000405\t0\t2016-12-31\t2016\tF...
4   5390\t00000000000007VG\t0\t2013-12-31\t2013\tF...
5   5390\t0000000000000917\t0\t2015-12-31\t2015\tF...
6   5390\t00000000000009VG\t0\t2016-12-31\t2016\tF...
7   5390\t0000000000001052\t0\t2015-12-31\t2015\tF...
8   5390\t00000000000010SG\t0\t2015-12-31\t2015\tF...
```

Do you have any ideas why it happens? How can I fix it?

Comment: use `sep=r'\t'`

Comment: @Mathias711 it works, thank you! Is it a regex?

Comment: Nope, the '\' in '\t' escapes the character, thinking it is a real tab, while you are searching for the text sequence '\t'. So not a regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the argument `sep=r'\t'` (note the extra `r`). This will make pandas search for the exact string `\t` (the `r` stands for raw)